# With PayPal's API, are you more likely to receive a "Success" response back if you include the optional address fields?

Tags: paypal

When using PayPal's API, are you more likely to receive a "Success" response back if you include the address, city, state, etc. fields VS just the required fields (first name, last name)?

Comment: Which PayPal API (express checkout, etc.)? I'd expect you would receive a "success" when you provide correct input values :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends mainly on how the merchant account is configured. In the merchant account you have the ability to turn on AVS (Address Validation Service) checking with credit transactions. Typically this compares the street address line 1 and the zipcode with the credit information on file. If this is turned on then definitely it would make a difference whether you pass address fields.

Comment: To add to this: it also strongly depends on the card issuing bank.